# Why does my while loop never end

Tags: php, loops

I've been trying to present my data from my database using PHP. My while loops keep running.

```
  function makeCollection(){
    $images = mysql_query("select file_id from images where collection_id = 1");
     //returns file_id

     $fileIds = mysql_fetch_array($images, MYSQL_NUM );
     //get file ids from $images into array

     while($fileIds != false){
      echo($fileIds[0]);
     }
  }
```

I have three objects that fit with id = 1, 2, and 3 (it's on auto-increment). Shouldn't the loop iterate through then stop after the third? It just write '1' for infinity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call the function within the loop condition so it can be evaluated multiple times. Right now you just call it only once, that's going to tell PHP to fetch only the first row. If it's not false (i.e. MySQL returned at least one row), your while loop will be infinite.

```
while (($fileIds = mysql_fetch_array($images, MYSQL_NUM )) !== false) {
  echo $fileIds[0];
}
```

By calling it every time the loop condition is checked, PHP internally advances the result set pointer so it can cover all rows in the result set. Eventually this function will return false and terminate the loop.

Comment: @Spudley: Thanks. I should probably delete my post and let you have the votes since I've maxed out my daily rep :)

Answer (score 3):

```
 while($fileIds != false){
  echo($fileIds[0]);
 }
```

You're not doing anything to advance the loop field inside the loop. You have a line immediately *before* the loop which sets `$fileIds`, but as things stand, it only ever gets called once because it is outside the loop.

What you need is to put that inside the loop, probably inside the while() itself, as follows:

```
while(($fileIds = mysql_fetch_array($images, MYSQL_NUM)) !== false) {
 ....
}
```

Hope that helps.